# Let f is analytic in an open disk centered at 0, D(0)

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives

Let f is analytic in an open disk centered at 0, D(0) such that 
$\forall z\in D(0) | f'(z) |\leq M$ . 
Then show that $\forall (z_1,z_2)\in D(0)^2$, $| f(z_1)-f(z_2)|\leq M |z_1 - z_2|$.

$\textbf{My attempt}$
Actually I don't know where to start I think
Since f is analytic and $\forall z\in D(0) | f'(z) |\leq M$, then should we use definition of differentiability?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* A disk is convex, so that
$$
 f(z_1) - f(z_2) = \int_\gamma f'(w) \, dw
$$
where $\gamma $ is the straight line from $z_1$ to $z_2$ in $D(0)$. Now estimate the (absolute value of the) integral on the right. Use that $|f'(w)| \le M$, and that you know the length of $\gamma$.

Note that the same conclusion holds for all convex domains, not only for disks centered at $0$.

Answer (score 0):

By the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions),$$\left\lvert\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}\right\rvert\leqslant\bigl\lvert f'(z)\bigr\rvert,$$for some $z$ in the line segment from $z_1$ to $z_2$ and therefore$$\left\lvert\frac{f(z_2)-f(z_1)}{z_2-z_1}\right\rvert\leqslant M.$$